# Environment variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK isn't set

Tags: ssh, 22.04, environment-variables, lxde, ssh-agent

## Situation:

For public key authentication i use Keepass2 with plugin KeeAgent.
All is right configured in Keepass2/KeeAgent and the key-pair is generated and the pub-key is copied to the server.
Keepass2 is started and the private key is loaded in it.
So if i'm logging into a remote server, i will prompted for a password.

### Basics:

***OS:***

```
lsb_release -a  
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
```

***ssh-packages:***

```
sudo apt list | grep ssh
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
...
openssh-client-ssh1/jammy 1:7.5p1-13 amd64
openssh-client/jammy,now 1:8.9p1-3 amd64  [installiert]
openssh-known-hosts/jammy,jammy 0.6.2-1.1 all
openssh-server/jammy,now 1:8.9p1-3 amd64  [installiert]
openssh-sftp-server/jammy,now 1:8.9p1-3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
openssh-tests/jammy 1:8.9p1-3 amd64
...
```

***Windowmanager:***
I use `lxde`

## Problem:

This had functioned until i updated from focal (20.04 LTS) to jammy (22.04 LTS)

**update 10.November**

A new installation of jammy with *.iso-image from today (10.November 2022) shows the same problem.

**Analyzing Results:**

Root cause is the missing set of the environment variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK.
(see https://github.com/dlech/KeeAgent/issues/372)
The environment variable must be visible system-wide.
To set it e.g. in a bash-environment makes it only visible in this session.
Using Ubuntu (Standard) as Window-Manager SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set, like something with gpg and keyring, but not in the way /tmp/ssh-XXXXXXXX

In focal i saw following (after starting and log in the window manager):

```
env | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-0mFzle55uRgI/agent.1862
SSH_AGENT_PID=1990
```

and

```
ps ax | grep ssh
1990 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch /usr/bin/startlxde
2038 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -s
```

In jammy i see:

```
env | grep SSH
<nothing>
```

and

```
ps ax | grep ssh
1006 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
8557 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -s
```

## Solution?:

I think that something was changed at system start, especially at start of lxde.